# Remove status bar on splash screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I'm using xCode 5.

I want to hide the status bar exclusively during the Launch Screen.

How can I do that?

I tried to set '**View controller-based status bar appearance**' to NO into info.plist file. and disabled 'hide during application launch' in general from project file (iOS 7).

Answer (score 29):

Add the following property *(`UIStatusBarHidden`)* in your Info `plist` file:

> Status bar is initially hidden

with a value of `YES`.

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS 9+ This proceeds to hide the status bar from all view controllers.

Comment: Works fine with iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

> and disabled 'hide during application launch'

You should actually enable that option if you do not want to see the status bar during launch. This will set the proper property in the Info.plist file.

Not sure if "View controller-based status bar appearance" is really relevant for this. This should only make a difference once your controllers are on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use XCode 5

disable 'hide during application launch'

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

put above code to **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function in delegate class.

easy.